# ASP.Net Specific Rules for sub-directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

One of my sub-site is a API project.
It does not support RequireHttps filter from System.Web.Mvc as does the Web project.

The Web API project is a sub-project within my Asp.Net project and is served as 
`https://example.com/api/{endpoint}`

I have looked at writing a rule such
{code}

```
<rule>
 <match url="^(.(?!\/api\/))*$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="^get$|^head$|^post$|^put$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^get$|^head$|^post$|^put$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
```

I want to block all http requests to my api endpoint. It should respond only to https

I can do this via a custom filter. Is there any way I could do this from web.config without writing any extra code?

Comment: Is there a practical reason why you want to avoid writing a filter?  I very much understand that it feels cleaner if it is in the web.config but I've never done it this way nor can I find it in the docs.  Besides writing a filter, it can be enforced at the hosting level.  Are you going to host through IIS or as a self-hosted web api?  Both options have a solution for blocking non https traffic

Comment: If I write a filter, I have to write unit tests for it.

Instead, if I can use the built-in features provided by web.config, then  why not?